# Loopings in VB.net with two text boxes

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have two text boxes in a user-input form asking for a VisitID(s) and to set a price. [image: Uner-Input Form]

It then uses the following code to update each VisitID with a single price.

```
 myCmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE tblVisit SET Price = (" & CustomerRefString & ") WHERE VisitID IN (" & VisitIDString & ")"
```

I understand that the above code loops for each VisitID in the VisitIDString, but how do I loop to allow updating each visitID with the corresponding line in the Price TextBox?

```
    Private Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

      Dim VisitIDString AS String   
      Dim VisitIDsUpdated As Object
      Dim myComma() As Char = {","}
      Dim connString As String
      Dim DataSourceBase = Report.GetDataSource("Connection")
      Dim ConnectionCollection = Report.Dictionary.Connections
      connString = ConnectionCollection(0).ConnectionString

      VisitIDString = VisitIDTextBox.Text
      VisitIDString = VisitIDString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, ",")
      VisitIDString = VisitIDString.Replace(" ", "")
      VisitIDString = VisitIDString.TrimEnd(MyComma)

      Report.SetParameterValue("VisitIDByte",VisitIDString) 

      '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Dim CustomerRefString AS String   
      Dim CusterRefUpdated As Object
      Dim myCommaRef() As Char = {","}
      '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      CustomerRefString = CustomerRefTextBox.Text
      CustomerRefString = CustomerRefString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, ",")
      CustomerRefString = CustomerRefString.Replace(" ", "")
      CustomerRefString = CustomerRefString.TrimEnd(MyComma)
   '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      myConn = New SqlConnection(connString) 'after  changes
      'Create a Command object 
      myCmd1 = myConn.CreateCommand
      myCmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE tblVisit SET Price = (" & CustomerRefString & ") WHERE VisitID IN (" & VisitIDString & ")"

    'Open the connection.
      myConn.Open()

      'Execute the statement and return a single value. If you wanted to return more than 1 value you need to add a loop here.  

      VisitIDsUpdated = myCmd1.ExecuteScalar()

      'Close the database connection.
      myConn.Close()    

    End Sub
```

Comment: Use right tool for the job - `DataGridView`

Comment: As suggested, you should be using a `DataGridView`.  You would create a `DataTable` with two columns, bind it to the grid, have the user enter the appropriate values and then save the changes to the database using a data adapter. Just note that you'll need to call `SetModified` on each `DataRow` so that records will be updated rather than inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to create your user interface, but if you have to do it this way (with textboxes), then you can solve the problem easily as long as the user enters the data correctly.

Assuming you have "id" and "price" data that looks something like this:

```
---------
|ID|PRICE|
---------
|11|1.11 |
|22|2.22 |
|33|3.33 |
---------
```

The user would paste these values into the `VisitIDTextBox` textbox:

```
11
22
33
```

And the user would paste these values into the `Price` textbox:

```
1.11
2.22
3.33
```

Then your solution relies on the fact that the index number of the item in the `VisitIDTextBox` textbox would match the index number of the item in the `Price` textbox.

So you would convert the contents of both textboxes into an array. Below is a simple example of you can do that for the `VisitIDTextBox` textbox.

```
'Any character in this array will be used to split the string
Dim sAAA As String = ",|" & vbCrLf
Dim arSplitOnValues() As Char = sAAA.ToCharArray()
'Create an array of visit ID's
Dim arVisitIDs() As String = VisitIDTextBox.Text.Split(arSplitOnValues, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

After doing the same for the values in the `Price` textbox, you would now have two arrays; arVisitIDs and arPrices

The **index** of each item in the arrays would now match up, so you can select from arVisitIDs and arPrices using the same index and get the price that matches the ID.

You can see this by using a simple loop like this:

```
For iLpr As Integer = 0 To arVisitIDs.GetUpperBound(0)
    MessageBox.Show(Me, arVisitIDs(iLpr) & "~" & arPrices(iLpr), "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
Next iLpr
```

When run, you'll get three messageboxes with values like this:

```
11~1.11
22~2.22
33~3.33
```